# function inside the attr() in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

can somebody tell the syntax to write function inside the attr() in jquery.

```
x.find('#Note_1').attr({id: "Note_" + counter, name: "Note_" + counter, onkeydown : "$(document).function(e){ if (e.keyCode == 46) { alert('hello'); }}" });
```

I need to execute the script for onkeydown inside the attr()

Comment: What does *"inside the `attr()`"* mean exactly. It's a simple method, there's not that many parts to it like there is for instance `$.map()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing something wrong. If you want a function to work when a key was down attach the event handler to the `keydown` event. `attr` is not intended to do something like that. It is used to get the attributes of the element.

```
x.find('#Note_1').attr({
    id: "Note_" + counter, 
    name: "Note_" + counter
}).on('keydown', function(e) {
   if (e.keyCode == 46) { 
      alert('hello'); 
   }
});
```

Comment: seperately keydown is working fine but inside attr() is error

Comment: Why do you suppose that it must work? attr is not intended to do something like that. It is used to get the attributes of the element.

Comment: wow! thanks for your answer works fine. I can append after .attr() then got solution.

Comment: @DroidDev :D. Welcome

Answer (score 0):

This is not the correct way to create a **keydown** function. Try using something like this:

```
$( "#target" ).keydown(function() {
  alert( "Handler for .keydown() called." );
 });
```

You can see more details in the **.keydown()** [documentation](https://api.jquery.com/keydown/).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I got the answer from Suren.